# Import issue Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine System is 64 bit and office is 32 bit

Tags: wpf

I have deployed a wpf application in the server with windows service using clickonce deployement. the application target as any cpu and the server is 64bit, After installing the application in client where offiice is 32 bit and the system is 64 bit and importing Excel file from the application getting error as 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
In 32 bit system with 32 Bit Office Import is working fine.Please help

Answer (score 2):

A common problem that affected me when developing SQL Server Integration packages that interact with Excel files. You need to install the 64bit [Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) on the target system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,since the application is used by many users its not feasible to install 64bit Access Database Engine in every system.Do you have any other option?

Comment: Perhaps changing your wpf application to compile as an x86 application instead of any CPU will force the usage of the 32bit ACE.OLEDB drivers without the need for installing additional drivers.

Only other possibility is that on deployment of your application, the 64bit drivers are also deployed and installed through a script?

These are just theories; I'm afraid I have no evidence to back either suggestion up.

Comment: the 64bit drivers are also deployed and installed through a script? 
could you please help me in this, how can i installed through script.
 I was wondering whether dll change to 64 bit will work or not.what do you think?

Comment: First idea depends on whether or not it is feasible to use a Windows Installer deployment instead of ClickOnce deployment. Windows Installer deployment will allow you (through [Custom Actions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd8h80ez(v=vs.90).aspx)) to install drivers.

To determine if it is feasible, I'd recommend looking at the [ClickOnce and Windows Installer Comparison table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: I agree with your option that windows Installer deployment will allow you to install drivers but the problem is from the past 5 years we are using click once deployment technique to deploy the application in the server so that users can directly install the application in their system using the link and now due to compulsion we have to make necessary changes in this process only.

Comment: The only option (and I do not know how viable it is), is to add a reference to the project to 64bit and/or 32bit ACE.OLEDB DLLs in the project itself and set them to "Copy to Local" on deployment. Perhaps the application can reference them that way without referring to the target system's installed libraries?

For reference: [How to: Specify which Files are Published](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy0fky2.aspx)

Comment: I tried your option copy to local but when using server name in click once link m getting error The deployment identity does not match the subscription but when using localhost instead of server name its working. Please suggest some solution

Comment: @KshitijKeshri I am not familiar with this error, but it seems common so I'd recommend checking the last answer on this topic as a potential solution: [clickonce-error-the-deployment-identity-does-not-match-the-subscription](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100050/clickonce-error-the-deployment-identity-does-not-match-the-subscription)