# Application Update fails using Click Once Deployment if Project Build Type is Changed from x64 to x86

Tags: updates, clickonce, auto-update

We have an application which was build/published in Platform x64 (64-bit) but now our clients want application to be run on Plateform x86 (32-bit). Setup was published using click once deployment. Now the problem is if we publish our application in x86 (32-bit) application update fails saying "Application cannot be started. Contact the application vendor."
Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100050/clickonce-error-the-deployment-identity-does-not-match-the-subscription).
Error details in log file is here.

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.18362.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    clr.dll             : 4.8.4042.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    dfdll.dll           : 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.18362.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\farrukh.niaz\Desktop\360Application.appref-ms| resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + The deployment identity does not match the subscription.

WARNINGS
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [12/9/2019 5:38:32 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (SubscriptionState)
        - The deployment identity does not match the subscription.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CheckUpdateInManifest(SubscriptionState subState, Uri updateCodebaseUri, AssemblyManifest deployment, Version currentVersion, Boolean& bUpdateInPKTGroup)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentUpdate(SubscriptionState& subState, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ProcessOrFollowShortcut(String shortcutFile, String& errorPageUrl, TempFile& deployFile)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100050/clickonce-error-the-deployment-identity-does-not-match-the-subscription
```